# Uploadify Progress Bar

Tags: uploadify

Can someone please tell me if the progress bar in the Uploadify plug-in will jump from say 0% to 10% to 17% etc. automatically, or does it need special code?

I'm working on a project to use the Uploadify flash plug-in to upload images to a site. I'm trying to see if the Progress Bar is working correctly, but can't get anything other than it jumping from 0 to 100%. I'm testing locally and have tried using the Firefox Throttler plug-in and a very large image file, but both don't seem to make a difference.

When I upload the same image to the demo on uploadify.com, you get the correct 3%, 10%, 17% etc. I had a look at the code here and I don't see anything special that updates the progress bar, so am wondering if it'll just work nicely when I put it live.

Thanks

Comment: Does the URL you are uploading to have the appropriate code in place to report back to Uploadify?

Comment: It sends data back when an image has been uploaded, which then gets handled in the onComplete function. Do I need to do something with onProgress?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same problem.